# How to access members of a class in Java

Tags: java, json, class, member

If I know an attribute of a member can I get the rest of the attributes?

I am creating members like this:

```
ArrayList<Events> eventList = new ArrayList<Events>();

for (int i = 0; i < elist.length(); i++){

JSONObject e = elist.getJSONObject(i);

    //store each item we want into a variable
    String id = e.getString(TAG_id);
    String event = e.getString(TAG_event);
    String eventCity = e.getString(TAG_city);

    //add the event
    eventList.add(new Event(id, event.toUpperCase(), eventCity));
}
```

And this is the class

```
public class Event {

    private String id;
    private String event_name;
    private String city;

    public Event(String i, String e, String c){
        id = i;
        event_name = e;
        city = c;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getEventName(){
        return event_name;
    }
    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return event_name;
    }
}
```

So if I know what event is in the class can I get Id and City?

The only thing I have figured out to do so far is:

```
String show = eventList.get(1).toString();
```

But what if I do not know the index?

Comment: Normally, class names are singular.  Event instead of Events.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ok... do you know how to access a member based on one of the variables?

Comment: You shouldn't change the Strings to public. The Java standard is to have private instance variables with getters and setters. If you need to change these strings, you should have something liks `public void setId(String id)` that changes id to the new value and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
public String getEventById(List<Event> eventList, String id) {
    for (Event event : eventList) {
        if (event.getId().equals(id)) {
            return event.getEvent();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This method works and I understand it except for why we change the type to LIST<>. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @silversunhunter: It's better to use the interface (List) than the concrete implementation (ArrayList) in your code.  The main reason is that it makes your code more flexible.  You can change from an ArrayList to a LinkedList without changing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are having some trouble understanding the various data structures at play here.  Let's see if I can start simple.  So given an instance of Event you can get the various fields doing the following:

```
Event evt = ...
System.out.println( evt.getEvent() );
System.out.println( evt.Id() );
System.out.println( evt.getCity() );
```

To get the various fields you have variable that points to a single instance of Event.  Now it looks like you have several instances of Event stored in an ArrayList.  So you might want to do some operation across all events in which case you'd want to loop over each instance in the array and do something like this:

```
for( Event evt : allEvents ) {
   System.out.println( evt.getId() );
   System.out.println( evt.getEvent() );
   System.out.println( evt.getCity() );
}
```

That would print out all events in allEvents ArrayList.  You could also write a method to find an event based on a given event ID.

```
public Event findEvent( String id, List<Event> allEvents ) {
   for( Event evt : allEvents ) {
       if( evt.getId().equals(id) ) {
          return evt;
       }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
 Event evt = findEvent( "someID", allEvents );
 System.out.println( evt.getId() );
 System.out.println( evt.getCity() );
 System.out.println( evt.getEvent() );
```

Comment: Ok, I think this is helping. I am going to change your findEvent code to `evt.getEventName().equals(event_name)` as I will only know the event_name. I edited my question to resolve the naming issues. Is this a method that is placed into my Event class or a class that is outside of it?

Comment: Since findEvent() must deal with a collection of Event instances (ie 1 or more) then it would belong outside of the Event class because that only deals with a single event instance and not multiple instances.  The cardinality between Event and a Collection of Events is different.